# git push and pull over http hangs on Windows, no errors

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-credential-manager

As the title says when I attempt to `git push` it simply hangs. This is on Windows 10 with existing repos and some new ones I created specifically for testing this. I've also tried two different hosts (i.e. github and bitbucket). My public repos on github allow me to `git pull` but my private repos on bitbucket do not. I set up SSH for one repo and I was able to push/pull however I've had issues using git over ssh on this system in the past so I'd much rather get everything working again over http.

So far I have tried:

- Restart computer
- Removed all git related credentials from Windows credential manager
- Uninstalled SourceTree (only other git related app on my PC)
- Uninstalled and Reinstalled git for windows from `https://git-scm.com/downloads`
- Disabled firewall
- Set git to not use git-credential-manager via `git config --global credential.helper cache`

Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `GIT_TRACE = 1` to see what it's doing when it hangs

Comment: @rbennett485 Thanks! git trace didn't provide me any useful output in my case but it did lead me to finding `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` which did prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering with this a little bit longer I discovered the problem... my global gitconfig has a setting called "modalPrompt" set to false. This apparently just hides the username/password prompts which makes it look like git is hanging.

*headdesk*

During my googling and SO searching I didn't come across this as an answer so posting for posterity.

Comment: I think it would be useful to show what command you used to correct it.

Comment: @AntonToshik No commands needed, just opened the global .gitconfig and changed "modalPrompt = false" to "modalPrompt = true"